# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2 , \sqrt 3]$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2 , \sqrt 3]$ an integral domain ?

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2] $ is integral domain: 
 take  element $a + b\sqrt 2$ and rationalize it, but im confused about  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt 2 , \sqrt 3]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It is a subring of the ring of real numbers.

Comment: thanks u @Arthur sir But im thinking that   It is  not  field,   so  need not be  integral domain

Comment: @jasmine If there are zero divisors in your ring, and your ring is a subring of $\Bbb R$, what does then exist in $\Bbb R$? Is that possible?

Comment: yes  possible   @ Arthur  $R$  can be  field , integral domain

Comment: If there are  zero  divisor then R will not form integral domain...So i think  not  possible

Comment: @jasmine Yes, that's right! There are no zero divisors in $\Bbb R$, so there cannot be zero divisors in any of its subrings either.

Comment: thanks u sir @Arthur